# How to create a STARTTLS connection in Websockets or AJAX

Tags: client-side, starttls

I would like to know how to create a connection from a client web browser to a server if it support STARTTLS.

SSL/TLS layer involve using a different port. STARTLS aim at making both encrypted/unecrypted version of the protocol availaible on the same port.

Websockets and Ajax are just suggestion. Any working method (like RAW socket API) are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear: why does it mention web browsers and STARTTLS in the same sentence? Probably you are confusing TLS(SSL) with STARTTLS.

Encrypted WebSockets connections are created using the *wss:* URI scheme:

```
websocket = new WebSocket('wss://server.com');
```

And of course encrypted HTTP connections are created using the *https:* URI scheme in the first place.

STARTTLS is a command which is used to upgrade the connection from clear text to TLS encrypted in some protocols such as SMTP or LDAP.